# how to create a regex for non-english letters with vba's regex 5.5

Tags: regex, vba, excel, hebrew

I'm working with VBA, and started using the RegEX library, for finding numerals and/or english text I had no problem so far, but now i need to use it on text fields that contain a mix of numbers and hebrew letters (addresses that has several possible formats).

I have managed to use it in a "dumb" way, i can find literals and some short patterns (such as, finding any combination that means a postal box - a two letter combined with any non-letter non number between them), but I can't use something like `\w` for english - and that would make my life a whole lot better.

is there anyway to create "custom" regular expressions and save them as variables? for example i would like to make this (a regEx for a single hebrew word):

```
regEx.Pattern = "(א|ב|ג|ד|ה|ו|ז|ח|ט|י|כ|ל|מ|נ|ס|ע|פ|צ|ק|ר|ש|ת|ם|ן|ף|ץ)+"
```

and save it as `\מ` for instance or even a `\hw` (short for hebrew word), as i need to make several types of patterns and several possible formats to recognize, and it will save me a lot of frustration (as already the IDE don't have the best interactions with hebrew letters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own character class, and use it in your code:

```
Dim hw As String
hw = "[אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתםןףץ]+"
regEx.Pattern = "^" + hw + "$" ' to match an isolated Hebrew word
```

or

```
regEx.Pattern = hw + " " + hw ' to match two Hebrew words separated with a space
```

However, you cannot "name" it to address like `\hw`.

Comment: I updated the answer. BTW, you should watch out for word boundaries, in VBA, you can always rely on anchors (`^` and `$`) and also on word boundaries (`\b`). Also, please visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html for more details on VBA regexes.